# Mixing preference screen with normal xml file in android

Tags: android, xml

I'm new to android, so pardon me if this question is too simple.
I want to make an xml file that remembers if the user want to be stay login or not, by checking the checkbox. here is the sample layout (I just used a regular checkbox in the image below).
[image]

Is it possible to mix a PreferenceScreen with a regular LinearLayout in an xml file? if yes, can you show me the structure?

I tried doing this, but i get an error.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <PreferenceScreen>
        <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="checkbox"
        android:summary="remember me">
        </CheckBoxPreference>
    </PreferenceScreen>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvRegister"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="Not yet member?"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#5F61D9" />
```

I want it to look like just like the picture above.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense to me. The underlying concept is wrong. You must keep the preferences and layouts separate. Layouts are an UI design component. Preferences only serve the purpose to save and retrieve some settings.

Comment: is it impossible to do that in android? i just want to make the "remember me" check box to be saved based on the user preference.

Comment: But i've seen some android application that has "remember me " checkbox within their login xml. how is that possible? I don't want it to be separated from my login form.

Comment: Simply make a launcher before the login screen. Then from the launcher activity check (using Preferences) if the user already logged once. If so, simply launch the Main Activity. If not, launch the Login. Which, once completed, will write the preferences and then launch the Main Activity.

Comment: My question is, I don't want my preference file be separated with my login.xml, is that possible? I want it to look like the image above.

Comment: `is that possible?` **NO**. Hope it's clear, now. But what I described works very close to what you have illustrated. Only the logic is different.

Comment: thank you for making it clear. :)

Comment: yes, i've seen some tutorials about that, I'm just wondering if it's possible to mix it within the same xml file. thank you for the follow up answer. :)